# Klein $this not in scope

Tags: php, model-view-controller, twig

I have a Klein controller set up as such in the index file, I have verified that the .htaccess routes everything through the index file:

```
     foreach(array('admin', 'api') as $controller) {
         // Include all routes defined in a file under a given namespace
         $klein->with("/$controller", "$controller.php");
     }
```

And within the admin.php and api.php files I am attempting to access the variable $this as such:

```
      $this->respond('GET', '/phpinfo', function () {
           phpinfo();
      });
```

but when this is executed I get: **Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in...**

Does anyone know how to resolve this? It works on my local development server but not when I deploy it. Is there a way around this, I believe it may have to do the way the deployment server is configured but I am unsure what it is.

Comment: You are calling `$this->respond()` in a place where there is no `$this` so not in a `object context`, but probably in a index.php or something. Try using `$variableNameOfObject->respond()`

Comment: I think the $klein->with code is supposed to pass the reference as $this because I get a object(Klein\Klein) on my local server but NULL on my deployment server (I cannot change any configuration variables there).